# Beautify big one line JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have one big json resulting file, something like this:

```
{'status': 200, 'result': [{'query': 'AL1 2RJ', 'result': {'postcode': 'AL1 2RJ', 'quality': 1, 'eastings': 514617, 'northings': 206084, 'country': 'England', 'nhs_ha': 'East of England', 'longitude': -0.341337, 'latitude': 51.741753, 'european_electoral_region': 'Eastern', 'prim ...
```

It goes on and on, what I need, is to have this somehow as a tree.

I've tried with [underscore-cli](https://github.com/ddopson/underscore-cli)

Then with this command: `cat myfile.json | underscore print --color`

It Throws me this: `Error while parsing STDIN in mode 'lax': None is not defined`

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want this in javascript or python?

Comment: There's the online jsbeautifier.io and on Linux there's `json_pp`

Comment: If this is in javascript, there are countless npm modules that achieve this. Google 'prettify json'

Comment: Better in python @front_end_dev if possible

Comment: This is not valid JSON. In JSON string literals are enclosed in double quotes. Also, null values should be denoted with `null` instead of `None`.

Comment: @Alberto Maurice Meyer has already provided the link for your problem Have a look into it

Comment: Did you accidentally use `str(python_dictionary)` and get that confused with JSON? **Python syntax is not JSON**. Use the `json` module to produce actual JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On python you can select the indentation on `json.dumps` like this:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(t,indent=4))
```

that results in:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "result": [
        {
            "query": "AL1 2RJ",
            "result": {
                "postcode": "AL1 2RJ",
                "quality": 1,
                "eastings": 514617,
                "northings": 206084,
                "country": "England",
                "nhs_ha": "East of England",
                "longitude": -0.341337,
                "latitude": 51.741753,
                "european_electoral_region": "Eastern"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much